# How to get Font Name of selected text in Rich Edit

Tags: delphi

For some reason, I need to get the font names of selected text in TRichEdit. This code works fine if user is only using 1 font :

```
ShowMessage(redt1.SelAttributes.Name);
```

but now user is using more than 1 font. I scanned the properties of RichEdit but failed to find functions that will help me address the problem. Its already taking me some time. How can I get the fonts names of selected text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just created an RTF document with three lines of text, each in a different font.

The following code correctly lists the fonts used:

```
procedure TForm1.GetRTFFonts;
var
  i,
  Len : Integer;
  S : String;
begin
  Len := 0;
  for i := 0 to redt1.Lines.Count - 1 do begin
    redt1.SelStart := Len;
    S := redt1.SelAttributes.Name;
    if Memo1.Lines.IndexOf(S) < 0 then
      Memo1.Lines.Add(S);
    inc(Len, Length(redt1.Lines[i]) + 2);
  end;
end;
```

Logically, `redt1.SelAttributes.Name` can only name one font at a time, so to list all of the fonts in use, you would need to move the `SelStart` position one character at time through the document, rather than one line at a time.  You could do this with a trivial addition to `GetRTFFont` above.

Equally, you could adapt the code to restrict it to the current selection in the RichEdit by saving the current selection start and its length, using the above method to examine only the characters in that range and then restoring the original selection.

Comment: @RemyLebeau:  Thanks for correcting the ambiguity in the original.

Comment: This lists all fonts used in the text (or all fonts used at SOLs), not only the ones in the current selection. My interpretation of the OP's Q is that only the fonts in the current selection should be listed. However, of course, that only requires a minor modification to your code. (+1)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, @AndreasRejbrand.  I've added a bit about restricting the check to the current selection.